# Upgrade NDIS to 6.4 for miracast

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wifi-driver, miracast

I am trying to get miracast to work on my laptop running Windows 8.1 and it looks like the laptop meets all of the criteria except for a network card which supports NDIS 6.4 (mine is 6.3). Is there any way I can get toys version without changing my network card?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo and that should have read 'Is there any way I can get this version without changing my network card'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[NDIS 6.40 is already included in Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn449742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> NDIS 6.40 is included in the Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2
>   and later operating systems.

Make sure you use the latest drivers which supports NDIS 6.40.

Comment: I upgrade my windows 8 to 8.1 on my Lenovo Twist but I still am running NDIS 6.3. How do I get it to upgrade to 6.4?

Comment: do you use an Windows 8.1 driver or an older Win8 driver?

Comment: I don't see how this helps... (I have 8.1, as does the OP, but don't have 6.40)

Comment: post which network card yo use and don't downvote a valid answer. *facepalm*

Comment: But it's not a valid answer.  The NDIS belongs to the device driver, not the operating system.

Comment: A valid answer would be that you need Windows 8.1 (or Windows Server 2012 R2) or later, AND a driver designed for that operating system.  A lot of drivers were made for Windows 7 or 8, and they still work with the the newer windows releases, but they're running older ndis versions.  If this is the newest driver for your wifi device, you may be out of luck.